# Is it possible to have different applications set to different locales?

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, locale, regional-settings

In Windows 7 you can change the system locale to change how non-unicode characters are interpreted in different programs. Let's say that I want to use language X for most cases, but language Y for one single program. It is extremely tedious to change the system-wide locale and reboot every time I want to use this one program.

Is there a way to set locale on a case-by-case basis in Windows 7?

Comment: I believe I have found a possible solution, but it seems a bit hack-ey.

If anyone else is having this issue, try installing this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13209

Not officially supported for W7 but it may get the job done.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a virtual machine if it's just a specific application you would like to use in another locale.

Comment: That's a decent idea. Still tedious, but slightly less tedious than a reboot.

Comment: Also, perhaps you could change the locale for a single user and just use the program under a different user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application itself would need to support configuring a locale different from the systems. The system locale is a single global default setting for all apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can have what you need with this:

- Create a new local user.
- Log in with that user and change the Windows language of that account to which you need.
- Log out
- Log in with your usual user.
- Run the application you want to see in a different language with the "Run As" method. (Shift+right click on the shortcut and select Run as different user).

Comment: It is not possible to assign specific Windows locale to the specified user. And it is not possible to run Windows program as other user, it is possible to run it with admin rights (not as other user).

Comment: Sorry, it IS possible to run Windows program as different user.

Comment: Yes, it seems we had the same idea. I do not copied nothing I used it myself for my projects.

Comment: @NetVicious, how do you "change the Windows language of that account to which you need"? If you mean "system locale", it is system wide.

Comment: @QiLuo The selected language for one account it's not system wide. The installed languages are system wide, but each user can select it's language without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this:

You can keep your system locale set to X, and make a batch/cmd file containing the following:

```
set lang=Y
start program.exe
```

Where Y is for example: en
And program.exe is the path to your program.

Save it as something.bat and use this for opening your program. The updated LANG will only affect that program.

*PS: sorry for the very late reply, but maybe it'll help others with this problem.*