# Is it possible to set specific Windows locale to the specified user account?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, unicode, locale

I am trying to run Easter European locale (language for non-Unicode programs) non-Unicode program on computer with Russian locale. I have found this suggested 'solution' https://superuser.com/a/183942/451110 (it is mentioned in https://superuser.com/a/922772/451110 and in some other places as well) but I have doubts about it. As far as I understand then locale is computer wide setting and there is not option to assign one user (account) its own specific locale. Or I am missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question: **No**, it is not possible to set the Windows System Locale for a single user.

About running as a non-admin user account. That answer is probably answered with XP in mind, where it used to be a Run As option (instead of the modern Run As Administrator) where you would be able to enter the user of your choice. You can still achive it nowadays by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while right-clicking the program, and there will be a **Run as different user** option.

---

Now for your problem: You may be able to use Microsoft's AppLocale program to accomplish that.

It was developed for Windows XP and isn't supported for later versions of Windows, but as outlined in this guide it still works at-least on Windows 7 [**Using AppLocale for non-unicode programs in Windows 7**](http://users.wfu.edu/yipcw/atg/microsoft/applocale/). You can download the program itself from the [Internet Archive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20140329114826/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13209) of the Microsoft download page.

Another solution (which is officially supported for newer OSs up until Windows 10 is the **Locale Emulator** http://pooi.moe/Locale-Emulator/